# tenser flow in android only for prediction use

Tags: tensorflow

I want to make a model using tensorflow in my GPU server and want to use it in android for user service.
But full tensorflow framework size is too huge to run in android. So I want to use only prediction functionality in android.
How can I come this work easily?

Comment: Good question. I'm searching too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this needs to be done through JNI to the TensorFlow C++ interface.  Though there does seem to be a Java shim layer available.  I haven't tried it yet, but here is a decent discussion of it: https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-invoke-a-trained-tensorflow-model-from-java-programs-27ed5f4f502d#.mcaz69nvf